# what does "multidimensional" mean in my Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects (multidimensional) VBA reference?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ado

I have the choice of

```
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects
```

and

```
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects (multidimensional)
```

in my VBA references for excel. What is the difference?

I want to be able to create recordsets from ranges in Excel and then load them to a temp table in the DB.

Comment: first google results: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms675532(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ah, so it isn't want I want to work with SQL Server? I'm trying to get my head round what the word "dimension" means here.